# how to detect voice when application is in sleep mode?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing one iphone applicaiton.In which I have added voice recoding functionality. It works fine when application is open.But when application started recording voice and I press home button then it goes in sleep mode.at that time sound is not recored..

But I want to record sound when applicaion is in sleep mode.

Comment: did u find the solution.then pls post ur solution.pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include and/or enable the "audio" value in the UIBackgroundModes key in your app's plist to enable audio recording in the background.

Comment: Yes you are right . BUt can you tell me when the application detect the voice then which event triger.Thanks in advance